# Systemctl remove unit from failed list

Tags: systemd, daemon, maintenance

How can I remove a unit from the `systemctl --failed` list without rebooting the machine?

Background:
I have, amongst others, the following entry in the list:

```
● openvpn-server@intranert.service loaded failed failed OpenVPN service for intranert
```

This happened because I misspelled `intranet`, which is the actual productive instance, on the unit template's activation some time ago.
However, I now always get confused at first glance, when I check the server's failed units, since it looks like the productive service actually failed until I recognize the spelling mistake and remember my bygone typo.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Use [`systemctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#reset-failed%20%5BPATTERN%E2%80%A6%5D) to remove the failed status. To reset all units with failed status:

```
systemctl reset-failed
```

or just your specific unit:

```
systemctl reset-failed openvpn-server@intranert.service
```

Comment: Thanks. That latter one saved my day. Note to myself: Read man pages more carefully.

Comment: And you can reset multiple services with a wildcard - eg `systemctl reset-failed systemd-coredump@*`